# XML defaultValue property not working with some Android activities

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I have an issue with Android preferences and their XML defaultValue property. When I launch the activity in question on my phone, the app crashes because the default sharedPreferences string (android:defaultValue) isn't loaded. Instead, what actually gets loaded is the string that is the second argument of the sharedPreferences.getString() method, and that causes the String Tokenizer to throw an exception a few lines further in the code.

The funny thing is that this particular activity shares the identical preference-loading code as my other activities, which work fine.

Here is my code, I would appreciate any help.

DoorSettingsActivity.java

```
package ilj.tel.fer.hr.smarthomemonitor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class DoorSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    public static class DoorFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_door);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new DoorFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

settings_door.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="DOOR_PERIOD_SELECT"
        android:title="@string/door_settings_period"
        android:defaultValue="@string/door_period_default_value"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

DoorActivity.java (relevant part)

```
public class DoorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONArray resultJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    ArrayList<String> timestampsList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_door);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        TextView doorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.door_main_textview);

        String jsonString = "", dataAddress;

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String doorViewPeriodPrefs = sharedPreferences.getString("DOOR_PERIOD_SELECT", "none");
        Log.v("DoorViewPrefs:", doorViewPeriodPrefs);

        // Splits the input time period string (delimited by ;) into "from" and "to" timestamps
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(doorViewPeriodPrefs, ";");
        String doorViewFrom = tokens.nextToken();
        String doorViewTo = tokens.nextToken();
```

That last line of code is where the app crashes because "none" gets loaded as a preference instead of DOOR_PERIOD_SELECT.